# Bash PS1 prompt breaks line wrapping when generating ANSI escapes by an external program

Tags: c++, bash, ansi-escape

I am looking at making a custom bash prompt using a C++ script. The plan is to call the script from within the PS1 declaration in .bash_profile like this:

```
PS1='$(bashprompt.out)'
```

This part works totally fine. The problem that I am running into is that the ANSI sequences are being printed to the terminal. You can see this in the following image, where it prematurely returns to the beginning of the line.

[image: Test returning to the start of line]

I am defining the colors in the format as follows:

```
#define DGRAYORANGE "\033[48;5;202;38;5;243m"
```

In a bash script, I know the way to avoid this issue is to denote the color as non-printing by using `\[ \]` (like explained here [https://www.funtoo.org/Prompt_Magic)](https://www.funtoo.org/Prompt_Magic), but that does not work in C++.

This is what the prompt should look like:
[image: This is an example prompt i made using bash and not C++.]

Here is the C++ code that is being used to make the colored prompt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define ARROW ""
#define DGRAYORANGE "\033[48;5;202;38;5;243m"
#define ORANGEDGRAY "\033[38;5;202;48;5;243m"
#define DGRAYDEFAULT "\033[38;5;243;48;5;0m"
#define WHITEDGRAY "\033[38;5;255;48;5;243m"
#define WHITEORANGE "\033[38;5;255;48;5;202m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"


using namespace std;

void PrintPrompt(string, string, string);
string FormatCWD(char *);



int main() {
    int buffersize = 256;
    char hostname[buffersize];
    char cwd[buffersize];
    struct passwd* pw;

    gethostname(hostname,sizeof(hostname));
    pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    getcwd(cwd,sizeof(cwd));

    string stringCwd = FormatCWD(cwd);
    string stringUsername = pw->pw_name;
    string stringHostname = hostname;

    PrintPrompt(stringCwd,stringHostname,stringUsername);
}

void PrintPrompt(string cwd, string hostname, string username){
    string cwdString = cwd;
    cout << WHITEDGRAY << username <<
            DGRAYORANGE << ARROW << " " <<
            WHITEORANGE << hostname <<
            ORANGEDGRAY << ARROW << " " <<
            WHITEDGRAY << cwd << DGRAYDEFAULT <<
            ARROW << RESET << " " << endl;
}

string FormatCWD(char * cwd) {
    string stringCwd = cwd;

    int size = stringCwd.length();
    int slashCount = 0;
    int slashIndex = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if (stringCwd.at(i) == '/') {
            slashIndex = i;
            slashCount++;
        }
    }

    string outputCwd = "";
    if (slashIndex != 0) {
        for (int i=slashIndex+1; i<size; i++) {
            outputCwd += stringCwd.at(i);
        }
    }

    return outputCwd;
}
```

Is there any way to fix this issue by marking the escape sequences as non-printing (like in bash)? Thank you for any help you guys give.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the ANSI are being printed to the terminal." All I see in the image are some good colors. Is that not what you wanted? What is the issue in that image?

Comment: can you show your code, the expected behaviour, and what part of that isn't working?

Comment: I added an example of what the prompt should look like. [link](https://www.funtoo.org/Prompt_Magic) This link explains how the ANSI sequences need to be surrounded by `\[ \]` so they are not considered for length when printed. I also added the source code

Comment: Ahh so the issue is that **wrapping is not working how you expect it to.** From your research you expect it to be because you need non-printing characters. I see now. Take a reopen vote.

Comment: @cnmcferren Any reason to use 'c++' program instead of bash script. Will be easier to update - no need to compile/install binaries ? Not to mention that it is easier to debug.

Comment: @dash-o I think that'll make no difference for the issue. The program might be a reduced example, which we always ask for on SO, while in its original form doing some heavy processing that would be hard to implement in Bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that `\[` and `\]` are interpreted by Bash itself, not the console, so they must be explicitly present in the `PS1` value, not in the output of the program generating actual prompt.

Now, you want the non-escape chars to count, while colors are not to be counted. For this, you can modify your program to have two modes:

- Colored output (for actual prompt)
- Text-only output (for character counting)

Then you can use something like

```
PS1='$(/tmp/test)\[\r$(/tmp/test c)\]'
```

which would work for code modified to the following:

```cpp
void PrintPrompt(string cwd, string hostname, string username, bool colors){
    string cwdString = cwd;
    cout << (colors ? WHITEDGRAY  : "") << username <<
            (colors ? DGRAYORANGE : "") << ARROW << " " <<
            (colors ? WHITEORANGE : "") << hostname <<
            (colors ? ORANGEDGRAY : "") << ARROW << " " <<
            (colors ? WHITEDGRAY  : "") << cwd << (colors ? DGRAYDEFAULT : "") <<
            ARROW << (colors ? RESET : "") << endl;
}
```

with `colors` being passed as e.g. `argc>1`.

We use the `\r` escape sequence to go to the beginning of the line, enabling us to overwrite our already printed non-colored text with the fancy-colored one, making Bash think that the additional text and escape sequences (including the carriage return) don't take any space.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of resulting output]

Comment: Excellent, this seems to fix my Bash line-wrapping problems (I'm using a Bash function rather than a standalone program, but either way it's nice to avoid having to write all the logic directly in the PS1 string!)

Answer (score 0):

For Zsh shell users:
You need to use $'control codes' and additionally wrap them into %{ %} (instead of [ ] for bash):

$'%{\e[1;36m%}'

Yea, not so obvious.